# For Google Cloud Retail API, can you have the search and recommendation engines return different things?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to set up Google Retail Search so it returns the following:

- Store locations
- Products
- Site pages

But I want the Recommendations AI to only return Products.

So far I haven't been able to find confirmation that this is feasible.  Does anyone know if it's possible to have a different set of return values for Google Retail Search than for Recommendations AI?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: for additional clarity, I'm wondering if I could maintain two separate catalogs, one for search, and one for Recommendations AI

Comment: Your question is too broad. Show what you have tried and the results. For questions on Stack Overflow, it is important that you show that you have put effort into solving your problem. No demonstrated effort sometimes results in downvotes and/or closed questions. The [guide](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/) will help you.